# i just want creat a react app from my vscode with gitbash terminal. but my npm start is showing error

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, npm

```
$ npm start
npm ERR! path C:\Users\erdai\OneDrive\Desktop\react crash todo\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\erdai\OneDrive\Desktop\react crash todo\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\erdai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-20T01_23_10_337Z-debug.log

erdai@DESKTOP-7OPDBPA MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/react crash todo
$ npm run-script start
npm ERR! path C:\Users\erdai\OneDrive\Desktop\react crash todo\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\erdai\OneDrive\Desktop\react crash todo\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\erdai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-20T01_33_16_252Z-debug.log
```

Comment: And does the `C:\Users\erdai\OneDrive\Desktop\react crash todo\package.json` file exist?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error when executing `npm i socket.io` from vscode terminal window. It worked through Windows Command Prompt though. Reinstalling Node resolved the issue.